# How to write certain symbols and backslash more efficiently?

Tags: symbols

Hi all basically I want to write this:

```
         ≪ (\ll[tab])
     ≦ (\leqq[tab])
     ⩵  (\Equal[tab])
     ≶ (\lessgtr[tab]) 
     ≷ (\gtrless[tab])
     ≧ (\geqq[tab])
     ≫  (\leqq[tab]).
```

I can replace the `\` with `$\backslash$` but I want to ask is there a more efficient way besides using `$\backslash$` ?

The harder one is the symbols `≪, ≦, etc` are not showing like it should be..

I try to put it into code line, and out in the latex text as well, still not working.

Marijn helped me to get this works, but still error it can't show `$\Equal$` symbol
[image: working]

Comment: If you want the literal code to be shown then you can use `\begin{verbatim}` and `\end{verbatim}` around the code.

Comment: For the math symbols the easiest would be to replace the characters by the commands, since you have them right there. In that case the verbatim would only be needed for the second part of the line, for which you can use the inline form `\verb+ code +`. So one line would be for example `$\lessgtr$ (\verb+\lessgtr+)`. Don't forget `\usepackage{amssymb}` at the start of the document because it is needed to show the symbols.

Comment: Hi @Marijn, yes I learn a lot from your advice, use `\usepackage{amssymb}` at the start of the document, then use `\begin{verbatim}` and `\end{verbatim} ` The funny thing is why it is not showing when I type `≦` under `\begin{verbatim}` and `\end{verbatim} `, it only works if I type `$\leqq$`

Comment: The only problem is `$\Equal$` it returns `undefined control sequence $\Equal$` all others can show the symbol nicely, except this one.

Comment: For `\Equal` you need `\usepackage{mmasym}`. This package is included in MikTeX (on Windows) but not in TeX Live (Mac/Linux). If it is not available then maybe you can use a literal two equals signs `==` instead of `\Equal` if that is sufficient for your purposes (i.e., you don't need the single-character `⩵` symbol).

Comment: Thanks @Marijn, I tried the `\usepackage{mmasym}` it said in the log : File 'mmasym.sty' not found. \usepackage. I really don't know Latex till details or bottom up, since Usually I use Office software, just learning LaTeX this year, LateX actually is better especially for academia purpose or scientific writing. Bottom line is I use your suggestion by using `==`.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Unicode math and the used math font includes all desired characters then you can directly use them in math mode. For example in OpTeX, you can do:

```
\fontfam[xits]

$$
  ≪ (\ll) \quad 
  ≦ (\leqq) \quad
  ⩵  (\eqeq) \quad
  ≶ (\lessgtr) \quad 
  ≷ (\gtrless) \quad
  ≧ (\geqq) \quad
  ≫ (\gg)
$$

\bye
```

The result is

> ≪ (≪)     ≦ (≦)    ⩵  (⩵)    ≶ (≶)     ≷ (≷)     ≧ (≧)    ≫ (≫)

Comment: It does not works, `\fontfam[xits]` is not recognized, I am using TeXStudio. Still newbie in Latex

Comment: @FreyatheGoddess This is not LaTeX, this is OpTeX. But LaTeX is able to load Unicode-math fonts too. It uses different commands for this. My anwer is about the fact, that you can use Unicode-math (irrelevant if LaTeX of OpTeX or ConTeX etc.).

Comment: Hi @wipet, I was just learning to write in LaTeX this year, I see OpTeX is a LuaTeX format based on Plain TeX macros with power from OPmac. I am already comfortable using Tex Studio, what OpTeX features that can kill LaTeX?